# PNG or JPG? Which one shall I use?

Tags: wordpress, image, png, hosting, jpeg

I am currently hosting one of my technology news site on InMotion Shared Hosting and it is based on WordPress.

My question is, which one is the best image, JPG or PNG? It would be great if someone helps me on this section.

Thank you!

Comment: The answer is "it depends".

Comment: I'd say one of the most important factors is if you need the alpha channel / transparent backgrounds. If you do: PNG!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recomend you to read this one:
http://www.labnol.org/software/tutorials/jpeg-vs-png-image-quality-or-bandwidth/5385/